# Can't understand date parsing

Tags: java, date

I have string `"1/28/2013 3:26:51 PM"`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a");
    try {
        this.createDate = formatter.parse(xmlPhoto.getCreateDate());
        this.shootDate = formatter.parse(xmlPhoto.getShootDate());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to make a Date object from this String, but I get a `ParseExceprion` and offset = 19.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Are you sure your XML strings dont have whitespaces around them? You may need to trim them before parsing.

Comment: What does xmlPhoto.getCreateDate() return ? I mean the format.

Comment: your code will not work for inputs like "11/28/2013 3:26:51 PM"

Comment: @BhavikShah.. Why? It should work.

Comment: @RadAl it is String format wuth content "1/28/2013 3:26:51 PM"

Comment: I just tried it on another android phone and it works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AM/PM` marker may not be be matching with that from your default `Locale`. try with:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH)
```